# JSON From PHP to Javascript Parsing with single qoutes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parsing

I have JSON from PHP i added `addslashes();` which result into

```
["01","\"Mia\'s\""]
```

and when I passed it to the Javascript and try to parse it I got this error and I can't find a way to parse it.

```
["01","\"Mia\
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at convertJSONToArray (add_something:2830)

here's my conversion

```
// Converting json to array
        function convertJSONToArray(jsonValue){

          var arr = [];
           var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
           for(var x in parsed){
             arr.push(parsed[x]);
           }
          return arr;
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed it.
by replacing the single quote into unicode.

Comment: You don't need to add slashes before you send to JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: What's the loop for? Wouldn't `parsed` already contain the desired array? Also, what jQuery? Anyway, don't escape the apostrophe in the JSON.

Comment: Did you make that JSON String manually or use `json_encode($array)`

Comment: Your original JSON string is `["01",""Mia's""]`, this is invalid format.

Comment: actually if i don't add addslashes(), if i parsed it I will got an error.

Comment: @RoyMustang still shouldn't need to

Comment: The correct JSON string would look like this: `["01","\"Mia's\""]` - that is, double quote characters in a property value would be escaped but single quotes would not. If you are trying to create the JSON manually with string literals you probably need to escape the backslashes in the the string literals. Please [edit] your question to show the relevant part of your PHP.

Comment: I got the answer, I use replace, and I replace the single qoute to unicode.

Comment: How do you assign php array to jsonValue in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're constructing JSON with plain `echo` statement and string. Perhaps something like this:

```php
<?php

$data = array("01","Mia's");
$escaped = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
  $escaped[] = '"' . addslashes($value) . '"';
}
echo '[' . implode(',', $escaped) . ']';

?>
```

This is actually error prone and not flexible.

You may use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate JSON. It will correctly take care of escaping and encoding for you. No need to do your own [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

```php
<?php

echo json_encode(array("01","Mia's", 'my "Hello"'));

?>
```

Will return:

```json
["01","Mia's","my \"Hello\""]
```